# Grails: how do bind domain classes with condition

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes in Grails that will interact with corresponding form fields for state and country.  Is there any way to conditionally bind them so that a user can't make the mistake of trying to submit something wrong.   For instance,  "Chicago, IL" would be valid, but "Chicago, Mexico" would be invalid.  Would it be easier to do this within the gsp or the controller?  Thanks for the help - this is something I haven't attempted before.

```
class State {

    String name
    String value
    int orderNumber = 0

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:false, maxSize:50, blank:false
        value nullable:false, maxSize:100, blank:false
    }

    String toString(){
        "$name - $value"
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'state'
        cache: 'read-write'
        columns{
            id column:'id'
            name column:'name'   //abbreviation
            value column:'value' //state name
            orderNumber column:'order_number'  // numerical list order
        }
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}

class Country {

    String name
    String value
    int orderNumber = 0

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:false, maxSize:50, blank:false
        value nullable:false, maxSize:100, blank:false
    }

    String toString(){
        "$name - $value"
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'country'
        cache: 'read-write'
        columns{
            id column:'id'
            name column:'name'  //abbreviation
            value column:'value' // country name
            orderNumber column:'order_number'  // numerical list order
        }
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

Form fields

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
    State<g:select name="State" from="" value="" class="form-control" type="text" label="state" required="true"/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
    Country<g:select name="Country" from="" class="form-control"  type="text" label="country" required="true"/>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at ajaxdependancyselection plugin, it tries to answer such sort of issues, I think there is a couple of more similar to it

Answer (score 2):

You will need to consume the form input into a [command object](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0/guide/single.html#commandObjects), and have a [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) on that command object with your validation logic. Plenty of good details in the docs.

Good luck!